# How can I store faq's information in a java .properties file?

Tags: java, properties

I have a bunch of questions and answers that I need to store in a java .properties file.  How can I do this easily?

I was thinking something like

```
faq.question.1 = This is question 1.
faq.question.2 = This is question 2.
faq.question.3 = This is question 3.

faq.answers.1 = This is answer 1.
faq.answers.2 = This is answer 2.
faq.answers.2 = This is answer 3.
```

Is this the best way to store the questions/answers in a properties file?  Can I use numbers to delineate between the different questions/answers?

Comment: Sure, but ew; yuck. You can use the numbers, but you basically need to read everything in then parse the keys to do anything useful. I'd consider... well, just about anything else.

Comment: So we have several different sites that each have different faq's that we need to read in.  So I'm looking for a way to keep all the code the same and just have a separate file with the faq's in it.

Comment: Do you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: We we're thinking about doing it that way... But didn't want to put the crud infrastructure in place.  Also we have a tech writer who is non-technical that we would like to just give this document to and have her write it up.

Comment: You don't need to make a full CRUD app; put it in an embedded database. Write a script to convert from a readable text format (which a property file really isn't) into the embedded DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work.

However, assuming:

- the files are dedicated, arbitrary buckets of FAQs
- do not require localization
- do not require an ordering that cannot be inferred from the question (e.g. alphabetical)
- do not require context-based filtering (e.g. on an id number)

...consider using the question as the key:

```
question=answer
```

If you intend to hand-edit these files be aware of the requirements of the file format.
For the question `Question: 'Hello World' == what in Japanese?` and the answer `Answer — 'Hello World' == 'こんにちは世界'` the standard ISO-8859-1 stored form would be:

```
Question\:\ 'Hello\ World'\ \=\=\ what\ in\ Japanese?=Answer \u2014 'Hello World' \=\= '\u3053\u3093\u306B\u3061\u306F\u4E16\u754C'
```

Otherwise, consider a format like JSON or XML that allows greater correlation of question to answer and the addition of other properties:

```
[{
  "question":"Question: 'Hello World' == what in Japanese?",
  "answer":"Answer — 'Hello World' == 'こんにちは世界'"
}]
```

If you have a web-based application where FAQs need to be updated without rebuild and deployment overhead use a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store faq in properties file consider to change key with a question. Like this:

```
This is question 1. = This is answer 1.
This is question 2. = This is answer 2.
```